# HP Envy X2 linux install

Tags: linux, hp

I have an HP Envy x2 tablet-laptop with windows 8 preinstalled and i want to install Kali Linux in it. I have created a bootable usb with kali in it and when i boot from the usb and enter the install menu of kali and click install a black screen popus up and nothing happens after that. I have tried to manually set up linux and initrd but still the same problem. I also tried with other linux distros but nothing can be installed. i have disabled secure boot from the BIOS too. I also tried to run a live usb without installation but it cant run either. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I have tried a lot of linux distros as you can see and nothing works. It's not that i have tried only with Kali. I tried also with Ubuntu,Lubuntu,Mint,Centos and nothing works. Also i have kali installed in another laptop

Comment: If nothing works ***on this laptop**,* then maybe there’s something wrong with the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that HP Envy X2 does not use an Intel x86 processor, but an ARM one. So whichever distribution you plan to use, you'll need an ARM version of it.

While it would be theoretically possible to build a multi-architecture OS installation media, all the Linux installation media I've seen have only included a single processor architecture. So a Linux installation media for the x86 processor architecture won't boot an ARM device, and vice versa.